# java.util.ServiceLoader not loading my provider class

Tags: java, serviceloader

I am trying to put together a basic SPI-based registry of Handlers, which I lookup from a HandlerRegistry.  When I use the ServiceLoader.load(Handler.class) to initialize the providers, and then iterate the list to lazily load them, I am not seeing any instances of the class.  Keeping this as simple as possible, my HandlerRegistry class is:

```
public class HandlerRegistry 
{
  private static HandlerRegistry registry;

  private ServiceLoader<Handler> handlerLoader;

  private HandlerRegistry()
  {
    handlerLoader = ServiceLoader.load(Handler.class);
  }

  public static synchronized HandlerRegistry getRegistry()
  {
    if (registry == null) {
      registry = new HandlerRegistry();
      registry.init();
    }
    return registry;
  }

  private void init()
  {
System.out.println("HandlerRegistry.init()");
  }

  public Handler lookup(String item)
  {
System.out.println("lookup("+item+")");
    try {
      Iterator<Handler> it = handlerLoader.iterator();
      while (it.hasNext()) {
        Handler handler = it.next();
System.out.println("found handler "+handler);
      }
    }
    catch (ServiceConfigurationError err) {
      err.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

I have a com.example.handler.Handler interface (empty for now for simplicity), and a com.example.handler.handlers.DummyHandler class which implements that interface.  I have created a file in my jar called META-INF/services/com.example.handler.Handler, which contains the single line

```
com.example.handler.handlers.DummyHandler
```

according to the javadoc.  My unit test simply calls the lookup() method to verify looking up the handler for an item.  Of course there will eventulaly need to be a check of some kind to see if this is the right handler for this item, but at this point I am not even seeing my DummyHandler class get loaded by the registry.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The answer appears to be in the sensitivity to exactly how this is configured.  I had been placing my provider name resource file (the one named com.example.handler.Handler) directly in the top level project directory, i.e., /resources/META-INF/services/com.example.handler.Handler.  I had configured my build.gradle to pull the file out and put it into the jar:

```
jar { from('resources') { include 'META-INF/services/*.*' } }
```

When I inspected the jar file, the file was there, right where I expected it to be, so I thought all was well.  On a kick, I happened to move the resources folder from  down under src/main, and presto! it works.  I inspected the jar file and it appears identical to one built the previous way, but for some reason this one works.  I will update further if I can determine a difference, but at least my test case works now.

Comment: Another key was making sure to use UTF-8 encoding **without** the byte-order mark for the resource file.  When the BOM was included, it got interpreted as part of the class name and caused build problems.

Comment: In case anyone else revisits this, I have it working in one Java project, but if I bundle it up in a utility jar and try to use it in another project, `java.nio.Files#probeContentType()` doesn't find my implementation of `java.nio.file.spi.FileTypeDetector`. The service provider goes off looking for my `META-INF/java.nio.file.spi.FileTypeDetector` service implementation list, but doesn't find it.

Comment: Hi @bachman, I'm having the same problem. I have a Provider (super class), and there are three child classes. One from axis2-jaxws jar, second from jdk's rt.jar and the third one is from jaxws-rt.jar. I want the child from axis2-jaxws.jar but the ServideLoader is returning the one from jaxws-rt.jar. When I remove the jaxws-rt.jar, everything works fine. But I'm not sure if this is a good idea, as SOAP webservice require some jars during the runtime only. Do you or anyone remember a solution for this?